# Soot: can Soot analyze .war package?

Tags: soot

[Soot](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot) is a Java optimization framework. I am using Soot to analyze some micro-service projects. Now, all I know is that Soot accepts .jar, .zip, .dex, .apk and source codes as input. However, some of them will be packaged into .war. Does Soot support .war analysis? And is there any relevant help info?

Answer (score 2):

no direct support but not that hard to hack,
giving Soot load bytecodes by [SourceLocator](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot/blob/develop/src/main/java/soot/SourceLocator.java), pre-defined support types are `jar`, `zip`, `apk`, `dex`, `directory`, `jrt` ,see [here](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot/blob/b9c2eeb8515fa1d11493a1f35ee919ff3dc255ad/src/main/java/soot/SourceLocator.java#L710),
the simplest workaround is by extracting the war file and set inputs (a.k.a `set_process_dir`) to the unzipped `WEB_INFO/classes` directory,
but you can extend `war` format supporting by hacking [getClassesUnder](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot/blob/b9c2eeb8515fa1d11493a1f35ee919ff3dc255ad/src/main/java/soot/SourceLocator.java#L316) and  [getClassSource](https://github.com/soot-oss/soot/blob/b9c2eeb8515fa1d11493a1f35ee919ff3dc255ad/src/main/java/soot/SourceLocator.java#L177)

Comment: Yes, I just unzip the war file and find the `WEB_INFO/classes` diretory, package it into a jar file. Soot can handle this kind of jar.